# Netsh change IP address of network adapter in windows server 2012 - error

Tags: cmd, windows-server-2012, netsh

I am trying to change window server 2012 virtual pc network adapter ip address via the command line below but it fails

can you help me ?

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" static 198.245.73.85 255.255.255.248 198.245.73.81 1
```

Here screenshot of result

[image]

Comment: Check the name of your interface: `netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces`